# In pooled mining, what is pdiff, bdiff and ldiff?

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty, mining-technical-details, terminology

In pooled mining, there seem to be three different terms for difficulty in use. Apparently, the Stratum protocol uses `bdiff`, BTCGuild uses `pdiff`, and `Ldiff` is common for various Scrypt pools as mentioned in this [bitcointalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=557991.msg6078779#msg6078779).

What are the meanings of `pdiff`, `bdiff`, and `ldiff`? In what way do they differ?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect, and answer, the updated question.

Comment: @KJO: Out of curiosity, why did you remove [tag:stratum]? I'm not much of a miner myself.

Comment: @Murch I looked at other questions tagged with stratum, and they had more to do with stratum-pool issues. Questions about stratum can pertain to difficulty, but questions about difficulty aren't limited to stratum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What are the meanings of pdiff, bdiff, and ldiff?*

The numbers are the current difficulty of the network(s).

- `bdiff` is the target difficulty of the whole Bitcoin network.
- `ldiff` is the target difficulty of the whole Litecoin network.
- `pdiff` is your pool's target difficulty.

As you may know, the difficulty is a measure of how difficult it is to find a hash below a given target value.

---

*In what way do they differ?*

*Is bdiff 1 == pdiff 1 == ldiff 1, or how do they relate?*

**TL;DR:** No. That defeats the purpose of having multiple difficulties.

This is a multi-part answer; I'll try to divide it in a manner that it makes sense.

---

## Bitcoin

### Difficulty

The Bitcoin network has a global block difficulty (`bdiff`). Valid blocks must have a hash less than or equal to this target. Mining pools also have a pool-specific share difficulty setting a lower limit for shares (`pdiff`, usually 1).

### Calculation

**How is `bdiff` calculated?**

`bdiff` is an approximation based off of a known hash where the leading 32 bits are zero and the rest are one.

> difficulty = difficulty_1_target / current_target
>
> (target is a 256 bit number)
>
> difficulty_1_target can be different for various ways to measure difficulty.
>   Traditionally, it represents a hash where the leading 32 bits are zero and the rest are
>   one (this is known as "pool difficulty" or "pdiff"). The Bitcoin protocol represents
>   targets as a custom floating point type with limited precision; as a result, Bitcoin
>   clients often approximate difficulty based on this (this is known as "bdiff").

**How is that value stored?**

> Each block stores a packed representation [...] for its actual hexadecimal
>   target. The target can be derived from it via a predefined formula. For example, if the
>   packed target in the block is `0x1b0404cb`, the hexadecimal target is
>
> ```
> 0x0404cb * 2**(8*(0x1b - 3)) = 0x00000000000404CB000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

Note that the `0x0404cb` value is a signed value in this format. The largest legal value for this field is `0x7fffff`, while the smallest is `0x008000`. To make a larger value you must shift it down one full byte positive valid value.

**How does one calculate (estimate) `bdiff`?**

Say your value is 1 (`0x1d00ffff`)

```
0x00ffff * 2**(8*(0x1d - 3)) = 0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

That would be

```
0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 /
0x00000000000404CB000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
= 16307.420938523983
```

[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty)

---

## Litecoin

### Difficulty

Because Litecoin is based on Bitcoin `ldiff` is calculated the same as `bdiff`. It is an approximation relative to a known hash (256-bit number where the leading 32 bits are zero and the rest are one).

### Calculation

`ldiff` is calculated in the same way `bdiff` is.

They both have a maximum of infinity (basically), and a minimum of 1/4096

Because Litecoin takes its roots in Bitcoin, this also means `ldiff` is an approximation, not a precise value.

[Source](https://litecoin.info/Difficulty)

---

## Pools

### Difficulty

`pdiff` is relative to the crypto-currency in question. In the cases of Bitcoin and Litecoin pools, it represents the same thing; but in, for example, a Namecoin pool, the difficulty may not be 1, or it may be calculated differently. This is confusing because the 256-bit number in question is `0x1d00ffff`. The number was not called anything initially. But once pooled mining started, it colloquially became known as `pdiff`. But it was around before pooled mining. Pools just happened to use it as their target difficulty, and because `bdiff` was already a thing, the name `pdiff` was transposed to the number `0x1d00ffff`.

Note that pools *usually* use non-truncated-targets, and *usually* use a difficulty of 1. This means that even within the same crypto-currencies there really is no set definition of what `pdiff` is; however, I know of no pools/pool software that contradict these rules, because they are desirable. Just remember that anyone can make his pool do whatever he wants it to.

**`pdiff` is relative.**

### Calculation

Assuming this is a standard pool, calculation follows basically the same as `bdiff`, but with one exception:

Let's say the target value is still `0x1d00ffff`. [The Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it) says pools usually use "non-truncated targets" So, instead of

```
0x00000000FFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

we get

```
0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Which, when calculated, yields

```
0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF /
0x00000000000404CB000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
= 16307.669773817162
```

[Source](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Target)

Comment: Is bdiff 1 == pdiff 1 == ldiff 1, or how do they relate?

Comment: @Dr.Haribo added more information.

Comment: Someone care to dig up some info on ldiff so we can complete this? :)